When pushing with a spell, ability, or otherwise, how much directional control does a creature have?
There are several ways to force movement for a creature that using the wording "away from you" or some variation:
The eldritch invocation Rebuke of the Talisman (Tasha's Cauldron of Everything p. 71):

you can use your reaction to [...] push it up to 10 feet away from the talisman's wearer.

Shoving a creature (Player's Handbook):

...you either knock the target prone or push it 5 feet away from you.

The spell Thunderwave (Players Handbook p.282):

On a failed save, a creature [...] is pushed 10 feet away from you.

My question is, can these creatures be pushed in any direction, as long as it is away from you? or would it only be the most direct "away from you" option? In the image below, if an ability allows me to push a target 15 feet away (3 squares), can I take the either option? or is the lower option the only viable choice?


I could only find this DnD-4e reference to the question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21691/when-i-push-a-target-do-i-choose-the-direction
but nothing for 5e. Also stole the image directly from that question lol.

I believe this answers your question
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208534/can-i-shove-a-creature-away-from-me-in-a-particular-direction

@DarthPseudonym Yes, but it leaves the other case ("push away") unresolved: but there are other questions facing that, for example https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149724/can-thunderwave-push-upwards

@Eddymage I'm not sure what you're referring to. The accepted answer only talks about the Shove Aside variant but my answer directly addresses whether you can do a diagonal push.

@DarthPseudonym My bad: I read only the question and partially the answer! I believe that indeed this a duplicate of that question

@JonAristotle Not related to the question, but I am fundamentally disgruntled by the usage of red for me, and green for the enemy rather than vice versa. :)

It's because you're the one the writer is pushing. :)

Note that if the optional rule on Diagonals from the DMG is in play, in the upper-right diagram the target has actually been pushed 20 feet, not 15.

@JonAristotle If the linked question does not provide you an answer, please edit to explain why and we can re-open.
